# How can I get the list value in a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

For example, I have import a component named `<pic-upload>` in the template, like

```
<template>
  <pic-upload></pic-upload>
</template>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    show: {
    content: '',
    recommend: false,
    albums: []
  }
}),
components: {
  picUpload
},
methods: {
  submit: function () {
    dataService.postpic(this.show).then(() => {
        this.$toast({
          message: 'success'
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and in the `<pic-upload>` component, it returns data and a method like:

```
// pic-upload component
export default {
  data () {
     return {
       imgList: []
     }
   },
  methods: {
     getUploadedImgList () {
       return this.imgList
     }
   }
 }
```

so how can I get the value of `imgList` array in the `template` component which I can post the data to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is sending data from a child to parent. In [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components), the parent-child component relationship can be summarized as props down, events up. The parent passes data down to the child via props, and the child sends messages to the parent via events.

[image]

You can have a look at the example [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events), you can define a methods in the parent component and invoke that from child component using [this.$emit()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit).

You can define a method `saveLists` in parent component:

```
<template>
  <pic-upload></pic-upload>
</template>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    show: {
    content: '',
    recommend: false,
    albums: []
  }
}),
components: {
  picUpload
},
methods: {
  submit: function () {
    dataService.postpic(this.show).then(() => {
        this.$toast({
          message: 'success'
        })
      })
    },
  saveLists: function () {
    //Code to save 
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can trigger this method using `$emit` from child component like following:

```
// pic-upload component
export default {
  data () {
     return {
       imgList: []
     }
   },
  methods: {
     getUploadedImgList () {
       return this.imgList
     },
     callParent () {
       this.$emit('saveLists')
     }
   }
 }
```