# Can't Target repeated component in DOM - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, dom, frameworks, vue.js, vuejs2

Excuse any syntax errors, It works perfectly, but I could have made an error copying over.

Problem: I have a component, 'dropdown', that is repeated three times with 
   v-for='(item, index) in search'
which is an array with three objects. Below in the 'filterInput' method, The for loop and if statement does indeed work as intended, HOWEVER, I do not know how to target the 'dropdown' element that matches the search[i]. I need to remove the search[i]'s element in the DOM when the search[i].text doesn't match the input.

```
<div id='app'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Start typing here...' v-model='input'
    @click='drop()' v-on:blur='close()'>
  <ul id="dropdown" class='nodisplay'>
    <dropdown v-for='(item, index) in search' v-bind:item='item' v-   
      bind:index='index'></dropdown>
  </ul>
</div>

Vue.component('dropdown', {
  props: ['item', 'index'],
  template: `<li><a href="#"> {{item.text}}</a></li>`
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  input: '', //reactive
  search: [
    {id: 1, text: 'Jacob'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Jeff'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Tom'}
  ]
  },
  methods: {
    drop: function() {
      let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
      dropdown.classList.toggle('nodisplay');
    },
    close: function() {
      let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
      dropdown.classList.toggle('nodisplay');
      document.querySelector('input').value = '';
    },
    filterInput: function(index) {
      //dropdown items in console: app.search[index].text = 'xyz'
      for (let i = 0; i < this.search.length; i++) {
        if (!(this.search[i].text.startsWith(this.input))) {
          //hide or remove this current search element from dropdown
        }
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    input: function() {
      this.filterInput();
    }
  }
})
```

tl;dr; how do I target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is how to have parent child communication, which I have answered today itself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276892/how-can-i-get-the-list-value-in-a-component/41277132#41277132).

You need to [$emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) an event from the child component and set the value used in input field, just like the example in [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events).

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id='app'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Start typing here...' v-model='input'
    @click='drop()' >
  <ul id="dropdown" :class="{'nodisplay': dropDownClosed}">
    <dropdown v-for='(item, index) in search' v-bind:item='item' v-   
      bind:index='index' v-on:getdropdowninput="getdropdowninput"></dropdown>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
dropdown = Vue.component('dropdown', {
  props: ['item', 'index'],
  template: `<div><li ><a @click="selectval(item.text)" href="#"> {{item.text}}</a></li></div>`,
  methods: {
     selectval (value) {
        this.$emit("getdropdowninput", value)
     }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: '', //reactive
    dropDownClosed: false,
    search: [
      {id: 1, text: 'Jacob'},
      {id: 2, text: 'Jeff'},
      {id: 3, text: 'Tom'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    drop: function() {
      this.dropDownClosed = true
    },
    getdropdowninput: function(value) { 
       this.dropDownClosed = false
       this.input = value;
    },
    filterInput: function(index) {
      //dropdown items in console: app.search[index].text = 'xyz'
      for (let i = 0; i < this.search.length; i++) {
        if (!(this.search[i].text.startsWith(this.input))) {
          //hide or remove this current search element from dropdown
        }
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    input: function() {
      this.filterInput();
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rk77dkuz/).

**Use dynamic classes**: I have also modified how to add/remove a class dynamically in [vue way](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax), instead of `document.getElementById`. Notice in following line:

```
<ul id="dropdown" :class="{'nodisplay': dropDownClosed}">
```

`nodisplay` class will be applied when `dropDownClosed` variable will be true and it will be removed when `dropDownClosed` variable will be false.

**How to Filter**:

To filter, you can use a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property in the `v-for` and whenever input changes you can filter the `search` array, like following

```
  computed: {
     filteredInput: function(){
       if(this.input === '' || !this.input){
          return this.search
       } else {
          var self = this
          return this.search.filter(
             function( s ) {
             return s.text.indexOf( self.input ) !== -1; }
          );
       }       
     }
```

See working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rk77dkuz/3/).

Comment: This is great! However, am I able to use this to have my dropdown list respond and only display if the search.text starts with the current input?

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't understand fully. I'm trying to remove list items from the dropdown when a user types in the input. If I type 'J', I want 'Tom' to be removed from the dropdown, and vice versa. I don't understand how I can select the correct list item created by my component to set to display: none if it does not start with the input.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson check the updated fiddle and answer: http://jsfiddle.net/rk77dkuz/3/